# non-parametric test: proof of Friedman's statistic

Tags: nonparametric, friedman-test

I am asked to prove that the Friedman statistic has two equivalent forms, namely:

$$
\Large
\begin{aligned}
S &= \frac{12n}{k(k+1)}\sum_{j=1}^k\left(R_{.j}-\frac{k+1}{2}\right)^2\\
&= \left[\frac{12}{nk(k+1)}\sum_{j=1}^kR_j^2\right]-3n(k+1)
\end{aligned}
$$

This is my attempt at a solution starting from LHS and trying to arrive at RHS. I feel like there are some cancellations of terms I should be aware of. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please explain what the "$R_j$" and "$R_{\cdot j}$" mean and what distinction is represented by the dot.

Comment: @whuber Rj is the sum of the ranks for each column while R.j = Rj / n (i.e. the sum of the ranks divided by the number of observations in that column). The dot distinguishes the sum (Rj) from the average (R.j)

Answer (score 1):

The last item should be

$$\frac {12n}{k(k+1)}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac {(k+1)^2}4=\frac {12n}{k(k+1)}k\frac {(k+1)^2}4 = 3n(k+1)$$
instead of $\frac {3n(k+1)}k$ as written on that yellow paper.

The middle item:

$$\frac {12}k\sum_{j=1}^kR_j = \frac {12}k\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^nr_{ij} = \frac {12}k\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^kr_{ij}=\frac {12}k\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {1+k}2k=\frac {12}kn\frac {1+k}2k = 6n(k+1)$$

Combine last two items, 
$$-6n(k+1)+3n(k+1)=-3n(k+1)$$