# Compute Exact Null Distribution for Friedman Statistic

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, nonparametric, friedman-test

**Problem Statement:** If there are no ties and $b=2,\;k=3,$ derive the exact null distribution of $F_r,$ the Friedman statistic.

Note: This is Exercise 15.35 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer.

**My Work So Far:** There are [two equivalent formulae](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372925/non-parametric-test-proof-of-friedmans-statistic) for the Friedman statistic, and I will use this one:
$$F_r=\frac{12}{bk(k+1)}\,\sum_{i=1}^kR_i^2-3b(k+1).$$
For our situation, this simplifies down to
$$F_r=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3R_i^2-24.$$
I wrote the following (quick and dirty) function in R to compute this statistic:

```
compute_Friedman_Fr = function(y)
{
   0.5*(sum(y[1:2])^2+sum(y[3:4])^2+sum(y[5:6])^2)-24
}
```

where I am considering the first two elements of the list $y$ as the first treatment, the second two elements as the second treatment, and so on. The Friedman statistic is invariant to two kinds of permutations: permuting the treatments, and permuting the ranks within treatments. An example of a function call would be:

```
> compute_Friedman_Fr(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
[1] 65.5
```

Hence, we can construct the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\textbf{Rank Array} &F_r \\ \hline
(1,2,3,4,5,6) &65.5\\
(1,2,3,5,4,6) &62.5\\
(1,2,3,6,4,5) &61.5\\
(1,3,2,4,5,6) &62.5\\
(1,3,2,5,4,6) &58.5\\
(1,3,2,6,4,5) &56.5\\
(1,4,2,3,5,6) &61.5\\
(1,4,2,5,3,6) &53.5\\
(1,4,2,6,3,5) &52.5\\
(1,5,2,3,4,6) &56.5\\
(1,5,2,4,3,6) &52.5\\
(1,5,2,6,3,4) &50.5\\
(1,6,2,3,4,5) &53.5\\
(1,6,2,4,3,5) &50.5\\
(1,6,2,5,3,4) &49.5
\end{array}
$$

**My Question:** This bears absolutely no resemblance to the book's answer of
\begin{align*}
P(F_r=4)&=P(F_r=0)=1/6\\
P(F_r=3)&=P(F_r=1)=1/3
\end{align*}
I feel like there is a category error somewhere. How could $F_r,$ with the formula above, possibly ever equal $0,1,3,$ or $4?$ Am I wrong? If so, why? Is the book wrong? If so, why?

Comment: You compute ranks *within each row,* not overall, so that total column ranks can only have the values $3,$ $4,$ $5,$ and $6.$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test#Method explains it (barely) and many sites, such as https://www.statisticshowto.com/friedmans-test/, illustrate it with worked examples.

Answer (score 3):

So, if I understand @whuber's comment correctly, I am computing the statistic incorrectly. I should be doing this, instead (as one example):
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
B/T &1 &2 &3 \\ \hline
A   &1 &2 &3 \\
B   &1 &2 &3 \\ \hline
\text{Total} \;(R_i) &2 &4 &6
\end{array},
$$
so that
$$F_r=\frac12(4+16+36)-24=4.$$

Another example:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
B/T &1 &2 &3 \\ \hline
A   &1 &3 &2 \\
B   &1 &2 &3 \\ \hline
\text{Total} \;(R_i) &2 &5 &5
\end{array},
$$
so that
$$F_r=\frac12(4+25+25)-24=3.$$

Many thanks, whuber, as always!